# Change title tag for a controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application.html.erb I have `<title>MySite</title>` in my `<head>`. But on the users#show pages I want to have `<title><%= user.name %></title>`.

What is the Railsy way to override this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to use an external gem called [meta-tag-helpers](https://github.com/mcasimir/meta-tags-helpers):

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<head>
   <%= meta_tags %>
</head>

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_meta_tag

   private

   def set_meta_tag
      set_meta title: "MySite"
   end
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @user = User.find params[:id]
      set_meta title: @user.name
   end
end
```

This is very similar to the `content_for` recommendation of `fivedigit`, but a much more robust & rounded solution. A Caveat here is the `meta_tags` helper will populate all your meta tags - including the `title` etc

Answer (score 4):

You should use `content_for` in `users/show.html.erb`:

```
<% content_for :title do %>
  <%= user.name %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your layout you can do this:

```
<title>
  <% if content_for? :title %>
    <%= yield :title %>
  <% else %>
    MySite
  <% end %>
</title>
```

Comment: I see the flexibility and conciseness in your solution. Thanks for putting this on my radar!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `controller_name` and `action_name` parameter methods to check which controller is being called and which action the controller is using to choose which title to show. You can try

```
<% if controller_name == "users" && action_name == "show" %>
  <title><%= user.name %></title>
<% else %>
  <title>MySite</title>
<% end %>
```

Note that the conditional will short circuit if the controller is not the users controller.

You can find [more on this in the rails guides.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not the desired behaviour, since it tries to set the title to `user.name` for the show action on any controller. When more titles are required, the if else statement quickly grows out of control as well.

Comment: My apologies, I did not notice that this was in the layout application.html.erb. I will update my response with an easy adjustment.